# how to import spreadsheet-like table with phonetic symbol(IPA) in R

Tags: r, utf-8, import, symbols

I tried to use standard read.table() function but failed, here is my code:

```
youphon = read.table("youdef.txt",header=FALSE,fileEncoding="UTF-8",sep="\t",quote="",comment.char="",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Warning messages:
1: In read.table("youdef.txt", header = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8",  :
invalid input found on input connection 'youdef.txt'
2: In read.table("youdef.txt", header = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8",  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'youdef.txt'
```

when R encounter one singular symbol, like ə,θ,æ, It will stop importing the data

Comment: Have you tried setting the `encoding` argument? What is your locale? What does the file look like?

Comment: Is your file actually UTF-8? If you saved it from Excel on Windows as "unicode text", it will actually be formatted as "UCS-2 little endian", not UTF-8. If that's your problem, the solution is to convert the UCS-2 file to "UTF-8 without BOM" (Notepad++ can do this for you), then open in R using `read.delim("my_utf8_without_bom_file.csv", encoding="UTF-8")`. In R on windows the IPA symbols will show in the dataframe as bracketed codepoints like `<U+025B>`, but will usually show up correctly when plotted with an appropriate font.

Comment: Thank you for help. I use notepad++ and I'm sure the fileEncoding parameter is right, I use Rstudio on Windows 8 64 bit. one record(row) in my table looks like this and each attribute is seperated by Tab:beautiful ['bjuːtɪfʊl; -f(ə)l] adj. 美丽的 出色地 出色的 迷人的 迷人地 Ernesto is in love with Norina, who is young and beautiful — but poor.

Comment: let me share the sample file with you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4aab3fho1gv5c9/table%20with%20IPA.txt

Answer (score 0):

I've first saved my excel sheet as unicode but I don't put any square brackets. I leave my IPA bare in the Excel file.

Then I open the unicode TXT file and resave it as UTF8,

then open it with Tinn-R: I check the errors with Tinn-R as it shows me exactly what R will read or not. 
Once satisfied: open the Tinn-R file with R.